# Facebook gives me two different acces tokens, PHP SDK

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-apps, facebook-access-token

I am using Yii as framework but i think that wouldn't mather.

At this point i use the PHP SDK to get the accounts information from an user, this works fine while my user logged in at first. But after 1 or 2 hours the access token expires and i get an error (which isn't weird).

But here is where i get stuck and i can think of 2 solutions but both i have no clue how to do them. First let me introduce some of my code:

To log in to my app users are send to the `FacebookLogin()` action:

```
public function actionFacebookLogin()
{
    $my_url = 'http://***.***.nl/app/facebook-popup.php';
    $permissions = 'read_insights, publish_actions, manage_pages, email';
    $loginUrl = Yii::app()->facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope' => $permissions, 'display' => 'popup', 'redirect_uri' => $my_url));
    echo '<script> window.location="'.$loginUrl.'"</script>';
}
```

After the user granted the proper permissions, the user is send to the `Login()` action:

```
public function actionLogin() {
    $facebookID = Yii::app()->facebook->getUser();  
    $accessToken = Yii::app()->facebook->getAccessToken();
}
```

(The rest of the login action isn't important.)

Now at this point the `->getAccessToken()` function gives me an proper access_token with a short life time. This would be fine unless the user is longer then 1 or 2 hours on my page, "some weird stuff now* after that the user has to logout and login back again. Then i still get the error except after around 10 minutes i get an new access_token which do grant me the needed permissions.

So to solve this i thought of 2 solutions, which i am unable to find the proper approach to use this.

First the easiest one.
When i go to the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/) and use the access_token my app gives me i get the info, but when i try to debug that access_token it shows that the access_token has an experation date. But when i use the same [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/) and let it generate an access_token on its own i get an access_token that doesn't expire at all.

**As asked an update on my handlings with the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/)**
I go to the API Explorer and change the app to my webapp. Then it got an normal access_token filled in automaticly. When i press the "debug" button it says that this access_token has an experation date. When i then go back to the Explorer and press the "get access token" button it gives me an other one. When i then again press the "debug" button it says that this access_token doesn't have an experation date. Which would be great if i can use this one.

So my first solution would be to get that last access_token (if possible) and store it in my database. Then when needed use the Facebook PHP SDK `->setAccessToken()` function. But how?? I don't have a clue!

Second solution i thought of.
I could also make an `init()` function which checks on every action if we got an valid access_token and if not get a new one or refresh the current one which is expired. This would have more server load then the first solution, and same with the first solution i have no clue how to achieve this.

I think that the main problem is that i find the Facebook docs kinda hard to understand, and i have no clue where to start from.

Any input would be very much appriciated!

Comment: This paragraph "First the easiest one..." is confusing. There are obviously two different calls at work here. You need to clarify exactly what you are doing for each in the Graph Explorer.

Comment: Edited my post, thanks for the feedback. Hope this is clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

You can either prolong the expiration time of the access token, as described here: https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/

Or you can embed the JS SDK, which on every page call will get a fresh short lived access token if the previous one has expired. (And shares it with the PHP SDK via cookie.)

Comment: If i embed the JS SDK does it update the access token automaticly or do i need to call this somehow?